# Why my last app is rejected in business facebook for reason 4.1 Risk of violation?

Tags: facebook

my last app is rejected in business facebook for following reason but I can't understand, why this happen?

> 4.1 Risk of violation: We are unable to approve this Bundle as it has been flagged as a potential risk for violations of Audience Network Policy 4.1 which states: "We reserve the right to reject, approve or remove any Publisher or app or site for any reason, in our sole discretion, including Publishers and apps and sites that negatively affect our relationship with our users or advertisers, or that promote content, services, or activities, contrary to our competitive position, interests, or advertising philosophy."
>
> If you have outstanding policy violations on an existing Audience Network account or app, please consider reviewing and fixing those issues before appealing again. If you are submitting an appeal, please ensure that the original app or account are compliant before submitting one for this entity. For more information and to appeal violations please go to your notifications in Monetization Manager to view other bundles or apps that have policy violations.

Comment: Please take the stack overflow tour (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what is and isn't an appropriate question here

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question which should be asked of the Customer Service department for the company you are dealing with. Please see: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746).

Answer (score 2):

we have got same email from facebook, and reason is we have 2 apps in our fb account which is removed by playstore so facebook count as a violance. once you live app with facebook ads you cant remove unpublish that app from playstore , if you do show facebook count as a violence and it will affect in your new apps review process.

there are no option like admob and other ad network to remove app from facebook monatization manager.even if there are option for delete property but this property is listed as ungrouped apps and dont know what to do with that ungrouped apps.